# Golang XML parsing only tags with specific value

Tags: xml, go

Is it possible to parse only xml items with specific values? For example, get only items with type **Foo**.

```
<items>
    <item>
        <type>Foo</type>
    </item>
    <item>
        <type>Bar</type>
    </item>
</items>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you cannot do that when parsing your XML. But you could apply XSLT template for your XML and parse result.

There is at least one XSLT lib for go: https://github.com/jbowtie/ratago . I haven't use it myself though. According to docs it isn't fully compliant yet, but filtering elements based on value shouldn't be a problem